# Bottom border of table won't show

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a table to show on my WP site and I'm just learning CSS, but when I create what I think should be right doesn't come out right. Only the outer right, left, and top border show.

```
.front {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

I put that in the table class. I also tried adding another bottom-border, even by itself, nothing. Here's my table code, very simple. Just trying to learn to use CSS.

```
<table class="front">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>test.</td>
<td>test.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">test.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I searched on here and tried this, but doesn't work (there were others things I found on here, but this one I remember):

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

I should note that I use a CSS plugin to make it easier for me to add it to CSS. Haven't used it much, a simple hide which works fine. Not sure if this could have something to do with it, just some extra info that may help.

Comment: Try to set up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: Must be conflicting with another rule. Can you try adding `!important` to that rule?

Comment: It was a rule conflict, !important fixed it. Didn't know about fiddle so will make sure to try out any code there before asking here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the `height` of the table or the container in which is placed.

Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4veg2dLg/) and try setting the height of the table to 100% like  this:

```
.front {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted what was there into it with no change unfortunately.

Comment: then also give `box-sizing: border-box` property to `.front`

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the following CSS accordingly; this will fix your issue:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
```

The problem is with the "box-size" being "100%", so the borders are pushed further. If you apply the CSS properties above to such elements, you won't have to face such issues.

### Edit:

This will work on elements that span across the full width (-or full height) inside another.
So, it will work like this with either "width" or "height", but here's both:

CSS:

```
.spanBox
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.redBorder
{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="spanBox redBorder"><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I put this in the right spot, but I put was was above into the .front instead of the height as well as the front-fixed (Separately as well) with no changes.

Comment: @ShogoMaki :: Sorry, I've edited the answer, see changes, hope it helps ;)

Comment: @ShogoMaki :: remember to mark the answer you prefer accordingly, (click the tick-mark by the one you choose). Also, later when you have more than 15 points, you can "vote" answers that are helpful -or not, but this helps a lot. thanks